# Workaround for Application Insights POST time property

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to POST data from an Arduino to Application Insights. Now, the payload requires a `time` property, like this:

```json
{
    "time": "2017-06-02T07:55:29.585Z",
    "iKey": "61c75aec-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.61c75aecae11483ba126665023ea73be.Event",
    "tags": {
        "ai.device.id": "Arduino Uno",
        ...blah...
}
```

This tiny thing has no real time clock, so my time stamp is going to be very drifty. I've tried to omit that property but the App Insights API complains and won't take the data -

```
"message": "109: Field 'time' on type 'Envelope' is required
but missing or empty. Expected: string, Actual: undefined"
```

Sending an empty `time` property also doesn't cut it.

Is there a workaround here to just tell App Insights to use its own time stamp on the received payload?

Comment: I know this is a very indirect work-around but could you just use some network-based clock to get the current time to populate in here? This all depends on what you're doing and how solid this solution needs to be. Clocks on IoT stuff is a hard problem (same with some crypto) because of some limitations sometimes!

Comment: The problem is that even if i implement that, i cannot trust it, what if it decides to go backwards in between NTP syncs, sounds crazy but time on Arduinos is research paper material :) I would rather have the other end stamp it.

Comment: I'd suggest submitting this as an item on the AI uservoice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/filters/top as i don't see anything there. (i was kindof surprised that we don't auto fill that field if not specified.  i can hypothesize why we might not *want* to, but you should submit it none-the-less)

Answer (score 0):

*For now*, yes, timestamp is required, no good workaround that's Application Insights specific.  For now, you'll have to use some valid date within the allowed AI time window (now-48h ago).

If you have an unreliable clock and you want all of your events to remain in relative order for one device, you could always pick a starting timestamp, and just make sure all subsequent events have a later time than that first event (a first timestamp+some offset?)  then at least the sequence of events is reliable if the exact time is not.

It has been raised internally and might be possible to do. I'll update this thread if I get any further details.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you can send any time that will make AI accept it (2 days back or 1 forward) you can use `ingestion_time()` method in Analytics queries. Like [this](https://analytics.applicationinsights.io/demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAAz2NwQ6CMBBE7yT%2BwxzbBKMcOfAtZqEb3EBXbBejxo%2B3QuJtMjNvJvF95Wz5UOEDfhprQODZCB2c6FgyuenFJLLzOOInslFcPE5odiyvMVKSN4Meo9toX2PhNLCazLxbNdrWo3%2BhF3X%2FmRrNOfptJpVvTqDENFwpGSbR0K1aesPEAdUXBzwo6awAAAA%3D&timespan=PT24H)

`requests
 | extend delta = (ingestion_time() - timestamp) / 1s
 | summarize avg(delta), percentile(delta, 99) by bin(timestamp, 10m)
 | render areachart kind=unstacked`

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted one day before the current date and it started working for me.

Comment: The idea here is to have the timestamp automatically added at ingest time. Of course you can specify your own timestamp but you can't do that if your device has no timekeeping capability.